# PHP header redirect not working if the session isnt set

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to check if the user hasnt logged in on a cart.php, if they arent -redirect them to login.php.

This isn't working so I tried putting it in an elseif statement. If they are logged in and are on the cart page, redirect them to the cart page, and if they arent redirect them to the login page.

It is working in the sense that it redirects, yet if I login, it still redirects to login.php.

Also I'm not sure why none of the JS alerts are working.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("Location: http://localhost/techiteasy/cart.php");
}
else if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("Location: http://localhost/techiteasy/login.php");
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Please Login/Register")';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Comment: You can't have output after you use `header()` to redirect

Comment: There also does not seem a lot of point in that `else if` a simple `else` would suffice

Comment: As far as I see, you are redirecting to `login.php` in the second case. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Once you execute a `header('Location: ...')` you have sent an instruction to the browser to go to another page. Therefore anything you ECHO after that will just dissappear into the ether as the current page is no longer there on the browser

Comment: I've tried simplifying the code which doesnt work. To only have one header - - -    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("Location: http://localhost/techiteasy/login.php");
}

Comment: _yet if I login, it still redirects to login.php_ Then we had better see what you are doing in the login script

Comment: @RiggsFolly , that's a good point - this code on the login might be the issue ,,  
 if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){

  header("Location: http://localhost/techiteasy/user.php");
 
 }

  

?>

Comment: Show us a bit more than that please, and post it in your question using the EDIT link

Comment: Just a question, before checking $_SESSION['username'] - I hope you have started the session with session_start() ?

Comment: I had a problem like this before, so instead of headers, to use js redirec. For some reason its not working now.      if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

window.location.href = 'http://localhost/techiteasy/user.php';


</script>";
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a redirect you can't add more code, the new page will call and the script of the new one will run.

You need somthing transfer from a page to another.

Usually i use a cookie with a short time (2-5 seconds), the new page will call check if the cookie is set, if it is show the alert and unset the cookie.

Here in the code you can see i put only an if statement (without else or else if) cause when the script fire the header location the next one code won't run and the new page will load.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    setcookie('notlogged', true, time() + 3;)

    header("Location: http://localhost/techiteasy/login.php");     
}
header("Location: http://localhost/techiteasy/cart.php");
```

In the login.php

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['notlogged']) && $_COOKIE['notlogged'] == true){
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Please Login/Register")';
    echo '</script>';

    unset($_COOKIE['notlogged']);
}
```

Try this ;)

You can also not set an expired time, it is just to avoid errors, but remind to unset every time, in other case the user only logs without passing from cart will wiew the alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use as like below. Do not need to check negative condition again. Simply use if-else.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("Location: http://localhost/techiteasy/cart.php");
}
else{
    header("Location: http://localhost/techiteasy/login.php");
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Please Login/Register")';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this on PHP5

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ header("Location: http://localhost/techiteasy/cart.php"); 
    }
    else{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
     echo '<script>alert("Login with vaild user and pass");</script>';
header("Location: http://localhost/techiteasy/login.php");
    exit;
     }}
```

For PHP7

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ header("Location: http://localhost/techiteasy/cart.php, true, 301"); 
    }
    else{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){ 
     echo '<script>alert("Login with vaild user and pass");</script>';
header("Location: http://localhost/techiteasy/login.php, true, 301");
    exit;
     }}
```